# How to check if a string is in a set

Tags: python

Edit:
The reason I as getting strange results was that the dictionary I was using(https://github.com/dwyl/english-words/blob/master/words_alpha.txt) contained many values that were not really words. The code I have below all works as it should. I thought it was because of the `if word in words` line but I was wrong

This is my code:

```
cipher = (input('what is your cipher? '))
alphabet = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
shift = 0
score=0
answer=''
scores=[]
answers=[]
with open('smalldic.txt') as word_file:
    words2 = set(word_file.read().lower().split())
with open('bigdic.txt') as word_file:
    words = set(word_file.read().split()) 
while shift<26:                           
    shift+=1
    for letter in cipher:                 
        try:
            answer+=alphabet[(alphabet.index(letter)+shift)%26]
        except ValueError:
            answer+=letter
    answer = answer.split()
    for word in answer:
        if word in words:
            score+=len(word)*13
            if word in words2:
                score+=len(word)*26           
    scores.append(score)
    answers.append(answer)
    answer=''
    score=0
maxscore=max(scores)
count=-1
for i in scores:
    count+=1
    if i==maxscore:
        print(i)
        print(answers[count])
pause=input('Press any key to finish')
```

### Shell

```
Python 3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 22:20:52) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
= RESTART: C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\Scripts\caesarcipherdecoder.py =
what is your cipher? this is the result
['uijt', 'jt', 'uif', 'sftvmu']
['uijt', 'jt', 'uif', 'sftvmu']
['vjku', 'ku', 'vjg', 'tguwnv']
['vjku', 'ku', 'vjg', 'tguwnv']
['wklv', 'lv', 'wkh', 'uhvxow']
['wklv', 'lv', 'wkh', 'uhvxow']
['xlmw', 'mw', 'xli', 'viwypx']
['xlmw', 'mw', 'xli', 'viwypx']
['ymnx', 'nx', 'ymj', 'wjxzqy']
['ymnx', 'nx', 'ymj', 'wjxzqy']
['znoy', 'oy', 'znk', 'xkyarz']
['znoy', 'oy', 'znk', 'xkyarz']
['aopz', 'pz', 'aol', 'ylzbsa']
['aopz', 'pz', 'aol', 'ylzbsa']
['bpqa', 'qa', 'bpm', 'zmactb']
['bpqa', 'qa', 'bpm', 'zmactb']
['cqrb', 'rb', 'cqn', 'anbduc']
['cqrb', 'rb', 'cqn', 'anbduc']
['drsc', 'sc', 'dro', 'bocevd']
['drsc', 'sc', 'dro', 'bocevd']
['estd', 'td', 'esp', 'cpdfwe']
['estd', 'td', 'esp', 'cpdfwe']
['ftue', 'ue', 'ftq', 'dqegxf']
['ftue', 'ue', 'ftq', 'dqegxf']
['guvf', 'vf', 'gur', 'erfhyg']
['guvf', 'vf', 'gur', 'erfhyg']
['hvwg', 'wg', 'hvs', 'fsgizh']
['hvwg', 'wg', 'hvs', 'fsgizh']
['iwxh', 'xh', 'iwt', 'gthjai']
['iwxh', 'xh', 'iwt', 'gthjai']
['jxyi', 'yi', 'jxu', 'huikbj']
['jxyi', 'yi', 'jxu', 'huikbj']
['kyzj', 'zj', 'kyv', 'ivjlck']
['kyzj', 'zj', 'kyv', 'ivjlck']
['lzak', 'ak', 'lzw', 'jwkmdl']
['lzak', 'ak', 'lzw', 'jwkmdl']
['mabl', 'bl', 'max', 'kxlnem']
['mabl', 'bl', 'max', 'kxlnem']
['nbcm', 'cm', 'nby', 'lymofn']
['nbcm', 'cm', 'nby', 'lymofn']
['ocdn', 'dn', 'ocz', 'mznpgo']
['ocdn', 'dn', 'ocz', 'mznpgo']
['pdeo', 'eo', 'pda', 'naoqhp']
['pdeo', 'eo', 'pda', 'naoqhp']
['qefp', 'fp', 'qeb', 'obpriq']
['qefp', 'fp', 'qeb', 'obpriq']
['rfgq', 'gq', 'rfc', 'pcqsjr']
['rfgq', 'gq', 'rfc', 'pcqsjr']
['sghr', 'hr', 'sgd', 'qdrtks']
['sghr', 'hr', 'sgd', 'qdrtks']
['this', 'is', 'the', 'result']
['this', 'is', 'the', 'result']
[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 4]
```

Comment: Could you add and expected output?

Comment: The behaviour you describe does not happen.

Comment: `"j"` should not be matching anything in the `words` set, the way you have provided it here. Theres something wrong with either your original code, or your original `words` or `answer` variables that you might have missed, or with the way you are incrementing the score variable.

Answer (score 0):

You code works fine for me.
Are you sure the problem is not in the counter?
The following code below for me is returning 'two', like is supposed to:

```
answer = ['j', 'mpwf', 'taub', 'tubdl', 'tuba', 'pwfsgmpx', 'apple']
 words = {'jam', 'jelly', 'tuba', 'apple'}
 score = 0
 for word in answer:
     if word in words:
         score += 1
 print(score)
```

Answer (score 0):

As roganjosh observes, the behavior you describe does not happen.

You offered a two-letter input word, `'it'`. My dictionary lists 160 "valid" two-letter combinations, nearly a quarter of the 676 possible combinations. I don't know exactly what input dictionary you used, but this effect may account for producing lots of `1` scores. For example I notice "mw" may correspond to megawatt, plus I see some [ISO-3166](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2#Decoding_table) two-letter country codes in your output. The dictionary I use is the `/usr/share/dict/words` supplied with OS/X.

To debug, simply use a print statement after incrementing the score:

```
    for word in answer:
        if word in words:
            score += 1
            print(word)
```

That will highlight the "surprising" `word` values.

Python's `in` operator is behaving exactly [as documented](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#in).

EDIT:

People mostly compile word lists to support spell-checking applications, which will tend to favor erring on the side of including *everything*. A moment's googling yields lots of word lists, but the first one I grabbed, from infochimps, turned out to have 427 two-letter words, an impressive 63%. Perhaps [SCOWL](http://wordlist.aspell.net/) would prove relevant.

You might want to use the enclosed (platform-neutral) code to access a fairly reasonable corpus of English words.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

# You will need: pip install pyenchant
import enchant


def letters():
    return range(ord('a'), ord('z') + 1)


def get_2_letter_words():
    for a in letters():
        for b in letters():
            yield chr(a) + chr(b)


def num_valid_2_letter_words():
    d = enchant.Dict("en_US")
    return sum(d.check(word) for word in get_2_letter_words())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = num_valid_2_letter_words()
    print(n, n / 26 ** 2)
```

What you really want here is unigram frequency. That is, rather than scoring a win for a two-letter word based on some boolean `check()` function, you would prefer to give a higher score to a common word like `'it'` and some smaller positive score for a less common word like `'id'` or `'mw'`.

I rather like the suggestion from Dunes about paying more attention to longer words. Suppose we lack unigram frequency numbers, and so are forced to assume a uniform prior on n-letter words, e.g. `'it'` and `'id'` are equally likely to appear in the plaintext. Count up the number of n-letter words in your dictionary, divide by `26 ** n`, and use that fraction in your scoring.

[Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) combined with `.suggest()` would improve resiliency to typos in the plaintext.

Comment: Zoran MR, your word likely isn't the biggest problem. Perhaps it is how you score matches that is the problem. Matching a 6 letter word should be valued much more highly than matching a 2-letter word. It should probably be valued at least as highly as matching three 2-letter words! But your current algorithm gives them equal weighting.